# What is you recommendation for a car antenna?

Tags: electrical

I recently bought a used car and it did not come with an antenna. There is a cap where one should be and a wire runs up to it.

personlly I would like a short one (6" or less).

What antenna would you recomend?

Comment: I think you need some more information to this question: what car, what are your requirements, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the biggest one you can fit.  Generally speaking, more metal in the air makes for better receiving.  Having an antenna tuned for the frequency you're listening to is of a slight advantage, often more than offset by having a bigger antenna.  2 and a half feet would probably be about optimal for auto usage.  That's 1/4 wavelength in (roughly) the middle of the FM band.  A 6" antenna is going to be less than 1/16 wavelength and not tuned at all.  Might suit your purposes if you only like strong/nearby stations, but definitely won't be ideal.